# PyTorch - scaling data for training and then rescaling results back

Tags: machine-learning, pytorch, autoencoder

I am working on an autoencoder network using pytorch. I have a dataset of rows that have 10 columns each containing values in roughly [-0.2, 0.2].

Since all builtin function for automated data preparation I know about work for images and other data types, I assume I have to rescale these into [0, 1] range myself, train the network and then scale every result back into the original dataset's size scale.

The scaling algorithm I used was (input is scaled data for training, output is result of network):

```
input -= min(data)
input /= max(input)


output *= (abs(min(data)) + max(data)) //last division was by "shifted" max
output += min(data)
```

Here is an actual code:

```
class AirfoilDataset(torch.utils.data.Dataset):
  def __init__(self, data):
    self.airfoils = np.copy(data)
    self.airfoils -= self.airfoils.min()
    self.airfoils /= self.airfoils.max()

  def __len__(self):
    return len(self.airfoils)

  def __getitem__(self, idx):
    return torch.from_numpy(self.airfoils[idx]), idx
```

```
class Autoencoder(torch.nn.Module):
  def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()

    self.encoder = torch.nn.Sequential(
        torch.nn.Linear(10, 5),
        torch.nn.Sigmoid()
    )

    self.decoder = torch.nn.Sequential(
        torch.nn.Linear(5, 10),
        torch.nn.Sigmoid()
    )

  def forward(self, x):
      x = self.encoder(x)
      x = self.decoder(x)
      return x
```

The results I get from this are really bad, but somehow deformed (don't know the proper terminology). It visibly follows the shape of the original dataset, but really badly.

On the other hand, if I don't scale the data put into training, the positive range of original dataset is represented perfectly by the autoencoder, without distortions. Obviously, the negative part is reduced to zero.

How to preserve "shape" of input dataset through training?

Answer (score 1):

You can use sklearn for that

```py
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler

scaler = MinMaxScaler()
scaler.fit_transform(input)

#here your model

output = scaler.inverse_transform(output)
```